# Search Gmail for emails without any CC recipients

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I have an email address that should not receive email directly, and want to set up an auto-responder if an email is received without a CC included. Essentially, a search for:

`to:me@email.com cc:[nobody]`

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't search for empty fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a complete solution to your question, but following filter is the closest thing I can come up.

```
-cc:(*@*.(arpa|root|aero|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw))
```

This will check only generic popular gTLDs domain, so all the new gLTDs will be excluded unless you add them in the list. You will get error message by Google stating too long strings if you add more (I'm not sure how many are allowed).

Comment: That's pretty cool! However, why do you need to list the TLDs? I just tried `-cc:(*)` and it _seems_ to work. Have you checked if there's anything wrong with that generalization?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You can scroll down the list and check; or you can send yourself a message with a cc.